# ZendFramework & Doctrine 2 & MongoDb - Entities not being found

Tags: zend-framework, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I try to integrate mongoDB with Zend Framework and Doctrine.
The integration worked good so far.
The only problem I have, is, that my entities are not being found (corresponding on the error message I got).

The error is:

```
Warning: class_parents() [function.class-parents]: Class User does not exist and could not be loaded in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 336
Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 336
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 336
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php, line 336' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:323 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(341): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true) #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(768): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendHeaders() #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(992): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendResponse() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Applic in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 323
```

My application.ini:

```
[production]
; PHP settings
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

; Set Plugin path for Lupi mongoodm resource
pluginPaths.Lupi_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/../Library/Lupi/Resource"

; Library include paths & namespaces
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Lupi\"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine\"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Symfony\"

; Bootstrap options
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

; Applicaiton Setup
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

; ODM settings
resources.odm.documents.dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Entities"
resources.odm.documents.namespace = "Application"
resources.odm.config.proxyDir = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Proxies"
resources.odm.config.proxyNamespace = "proxies"
resources.odm.config.hydratorDir = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Hydrators"
resources.odm.config.hydratorNamespace = "hydrators"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

My Bootstrap.php is empty.
Furthermore I have the Action Controller and the Resource from the Example on github.

My User.php:

```
<?php

 namespace Entities;

 /**
  * @Document(collection="users")
  */
  class User {

    /**
     * @Id
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @String
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @String
 */
    private $email;
```

My controller:

```
<?php

 class RegistrationController extends Lupi\Controller\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

public function init() {
    $this->repository = $this->dm->getRepository('User');
}
```

My example is based on this here: http://github.com/bittarman/zf-d2-odm, the presentation to this can be find here http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000bZ6y-Doctrine2-ODM-ZF-20110526.flv, but also on slideshare with the corresponding tags.

Thanks in advance for your help! =)

Answer (score 1):

You will see that in the two lines of config above:

> resources.odm.documents.dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Entities"
>   resources.odm.documents.namespace = "Application"

it is looking for documents (entities) with the namespace "Application" in the folder application/models/Entities (which you appear to have edited as I lowercased the e of entities)

Your namespace appears to be Entities, which means that it is looking for the wrong namespace.
Either, 
a) change your document to fit the config, so Application\User would be in application/models/Entities/Application/User.php or ...
b) change the config to fit your documents, so 'resources.odm.documents.namespace = "Application"' would become 'resources.odm.documents.namespace = "Entites"'.

Thank you for taking the time to watch my webinar, and download the project though, I hope you found it informative!

Comment: First thanks for you reply! The things you mentioned seem right and reasonable to me and I changed them according to your description, but no change :( Afterwards, I copied 1:1 everything from your project to mine (also the entities folder with it's classes), and still I got this error. I really don't understand it :(